# Latest ionic google map component fails

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

The Ionic google map component used to be `angular2-google-maps`, renamed to  `@agm/core`.

The documentation now specifies this incantation:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-maps
```

However, when I run:

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="<myKey>"
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is the component missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID=yourkey --save`

Comment: Sadly, no difference.

Comment: Did you remove ionic from the command?

Comment: Didn't help - the error shows 'Failed to fetch plugin'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I create a fork of the repository and install the plugin from there, that worked for me. If you want try to install from my Repo

```
$cordova plugin add https://github.com/Motoralfa/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="..." --save
```

I tried without Ionic command, but i think it can work too!

Comment: Sadly, this failed too. Maybe it's because I am in Scotland? I've given up and am back using @agm/core.

Comment: @jcsubmit Please retry one more time.